# CSS Hardware Acceleration in Phonegap App

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to use hardware acceleration in a phonegap application. I have read that I have to put a css 3dtransform for this pourpose. So, I have used a webkit-transform3d in the main class of my html element, but I continue to see some lag during the animation.

I want to open and close a box, settings is height from 0 to somevalue and viceversa.

I have write an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VG7V5/6/

As you can see, I have defined the class container in this way:

```
#container {
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em 0em #777777;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 15em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translate3d(0em,0em,0em);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0em,0em,0em);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

If I open the example with my Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2 I see some lags during the animation, with or without the transform3d enabled (infact in jsfiddle it starts with the transform commented). It seems as nothing change.

Is there something wrong???

Thx

Comment: hardware acceleration works if there's ressource, i do not believe that smartphone have high performance graphic cards to relief the main processor

Comment: Also the smartphones have a graphic processor unit.. And there are a lot of articles on the web about this topic..

Comment: yes but does it have a chip powerfull enough to do the calculation instead of main processor like a regular computer does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I have found the solution by myself.

As explained in this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

is possible to achieve high performance animations if they are of these types: position, scale, rotation or opacity.

Essentially the animation should not change the dimensions of the element, because it causes too much overhead for the cpu/gpu.

So, changing the height of the element, as in my example, is not a great idea. :D

Comment: +1 Great reference for phonegap (and HTML5) animations. I was using transitions using left/top attributes and was seeing some lagging in the animation. Using translate3d (or just translate) really smooths these animations out! Thanks!